# Run bash script on remote server

Tags: bash, shell, remote-server, sshpass

I'm trying to run a bash script on the remote server that is already on the remote server. I'm using ssh pass to do it but I'm seeing errors

```
test.sh (resides on the remote server)

#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "This is test"
adb start-server
```

sshpass command (I'm running this sshpass command from docker ubuntu image

```
sshpass -p password ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no user@host "bash -s" < /Users/user/Documents/workspace/test.sh
```

I also tried

```
sshpass -p password ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no user@host 'cd /Users/user/Documents/workspace/; sh test.sh'
```

I get this error message

```
bash: /Users/user/Documents/workspace/test.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

The examples you're showing are for a local script, and you said it's a remote script.

```
sshpass -p password ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no user@host "bash /path/to/test.sh"
```

that ought to do it.

you can try to find your test.sh on the remote computer:

```
sshpass -p password ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no user@host "find ~/ -name \"test.sh\""
```

Comment: Thanks!I get this error.------
Warning: Permanently added 'raenug451.local' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
This is test
path/to//test.sh: line 4: adb: command not found--------

adb is installed on remote machine. I want to run this remote script on that remote machine itself. Does the answer you mentioned does that. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with here-document:

```
sshpass -p password ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no -T user@host <<EOF
bash /Users/user/Documents/workspace/test.sh
EOF
```

Include `-T` option for `ssh` command, as mentioned above, to disable pseudo-tty.

[**AT REMOTE MATCHINE**] Ensure that path of `adb` executable is included in `PATH` environment variable. Else, specify it with absolute path in the Shell script.